# R - Getting dimnames of n smallest values in upper triangle of a matrix

Tags: r

Let's say we have a matrix like this:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(abs(rnorm(16)), ncol=4)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
m
#           a         b         c          d
# a 0.6264538 0.3295078 0.5757814 0.62124058
# b 0.1836433 0.8204684 0.3053884 2.21469989
# c 0.8356286 0.4874291 1.5117812 1.12493092
# d 1.5952808 0.7383247 0.3898432 0.04493361
```

Is it possible, in an efficient way, to get the dimension names of, say, the 3 smallest values of the upper triangle?

I have the following method:

```
#find the 3rd smallest value in the upper triag:
val <- m[upper.tri(m)][order(m[upper.tri(m)])[3] ]

#get the indices of values smaller than val:
ind_smallest <- arrayInd(which(upper.tri(m) & m <=val), dim(m))

cbind( colnames(m)[ind_smallest[, 1]], rownames(m)[ind_smallest[, 2]])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "b" 
# [2,] "a"  "c" 
# [3,] "b"  "c"
```

Is there an easier way, which is both memory- and time-efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
library(data.table)

setDT(melt(m))[as.integer(Var2) > as.integer(Var1)][order(value)][1:3]

#    Var1 Var2     value
# 1:    b    c 0.3053884
# 2:    a    b 0.3295078
# 3:    a    c 0.5757814
```

How it works:

1. `melt` converts your matrix to long format (type `?melt.matrix`).
2. `setDT` converts to a data.table (see [intro vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for syntax).
3. `as.integer(Var2) > as.integer(Var1)` gets the upper triangle.
4. `order(value)` sorts the long-format data in ascending order.
5. `1:3` selects the first three rows.

I think step 3 works even if the var names are not ordered, but did not test it.

---

Analogous dplyr code:

```
library(dplyr)

melt(m) %>% filter(as.integer(Var2) > as.integer(Var1)) %>% arrange(value) %>% slice(1:3)
```